# KNNImputer could not convert string to float: 'xx'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe and a column in it with string values,I want to fill NaN values with KNNImputer. I have 5 unique values in the column.

```
knn_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

df_dummy = df.copy()

label_encoder.fit(df_dummy['Column'])
df_dummy['Column'] = label_encoder.transform(df_dummy['Column'])

knn_imputer.fit(df_dummy)
df_dummy = knn_imputer.transform(df_dummy)
df_dummy.to_csv('imputed_dataframe.csv', index=False)
```

here is the error output I get:

```
  2068 
  2069     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 2070         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
  2071 
  2072     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, `"ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RL'`," occurs because the KNNImputer expects numerical input data, and it cannot handle string values.

```
knn_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Encode the string column
df_encoded = df.copy()
df_encoded['Column'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df_encoded['Column'])

# Use KNNImputer to fill NaN values
knn_imputer.fit(df_encoded)
df_imputed_encoded = knn_imputer.transform(df_encoded)

# Decode the numerical values back to strings
df_imputed = df.copy()
df_imputed['Column'] = label_encoder.inverse_transform(df_imputed_encoded[:, 0].astype(int))

# Save the imputed DataFrame to a CSV file
df_imputed.to_csv('imputed_dataframe.csv', index=False)
```

These steps should do the work

- Encode the string values in your target column into numerical values.
- Apply KNNImputer to fill NaN values.
- Decode the numerical values back into the original string values.

Comment: labelencoder is for labels(target variable) :) you should suggest OrdinalEncoder or OneHotEncoder

Answer (score 0):

[Prudhviraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8187167/prudhviraj)'s code gave me an idea to solve the problem, but [Prayson W. Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6858244/prayson-w-daniel) really solved it. big thanks.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

knn_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
OrdEnc = OrdinalEncoder()

df_encoded = df.copy()
df_encoded['Column'] = OrdEnc.fit_transform(df_encoded['Column'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

knn_imputer.fit(df_encoded[['Column']])

df_imputed_encoded = knn_imputer.transform(df_encoded[['Column']])

df_imputed = df.copy()
df_imputed['Column'] = label_encoder.inverse_transform(df_imputed_encoded[:, 0].astype(int))

df_imputed.to_csv('imputed_dataframe.csv', index=False)
```